# Why can this confusing #include"..\..\[etc. etc.]" statement work?

Tags: c++, file, visual-c++, include, directive

I want to add an **#include** directive to my *A.cpp* file, and the header file *B.h* is in the folder two layers up (for example, if the source file is in ***E:\A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H***, the header file is in ***E:\A\B\C\F***, of course, the names will be much longer than this), so I typed this confusing statement in Visual Studio 2010:

```
#include"../../
```

And the Intellisense feature in VS 10 showed up a list of the files, and *B.h* is in it! I don't know if this statement is correct, but I think there is something wrong with this. Could any of you tell me whether this is wrong or correct? And could you give me a better solution for this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong?  All of that seems correct to me.

Comment: Maybe because it's fragile?

Comment: How is it any more fragile than having to pass a `-I` flag (or whatever the MSVC equivalent is) to the compiler?

Comment: Do I have to pass this flag to the VS 2010 command-prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't it work? Have you ever done `cd ../../mydir` and checked what that does? It's the equivalent of that. `..` and `.` point to a special directory in both Windows and Linux. `.` is the current directory while `..` is the previous directory. So `../../file.h` would go two directories back to find the file you're looking for. After all, the `#include "..."` statement works with the relative path the file is located in. Usually when writing libraries and you have a main `detail` subdirectory you would try to access it via `#include "../detail/myfile.hpp"`, while other libraries such as boost opt for `#include <boost/config/myfile.hpp>`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to include the `"-I <INCLUDE_DIR>"` parameter to your build and just #include the header without the directory listed. The  is where you are telling the compiler and linker to look for your header files.

Comment: How can I include this? Can I use the VS 2010 command-prompt?

Comment: Go to your project's properties, there is an includes option there.

Comment: I think passing an -I flag is a better solution, according to the comment made by Carl Norum

Answer (score -1):

`..\` moves you up one directory, so `..\..\` will move you up two directories.  I suppose this is fine if you can assume the script location will never change.  If, however, you moved the script to a different drive you would be in trouble.  It might be better to include E:\A\B\C\D\E\F\B.h instead to future proof yourself.

Comment: You say "script" when the question is about C++. I can't imagine what sort of programmer would suggest hard-coding local include paths instead of using coherent relative paths.

Comment: I think I can paste this file location from the Windows Explorer, but if I change the location, it will require a lot of effort to change all references of this location. But I will thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @DanielKO I was just speaking in general terms as this could apply to any number of languages.  Based on the question we have no idea of the scope of the project.  I admit I assumed this to be small scale based on the question itself, which is my bad.  I obviously wouldn't advocate for this in a production environment but what harm is there in something small scale.

Comment: @VictorPrograss  You would run into the same issue of having to update the paths using either technique if the project is moved.  Why not include necessary files within a subdirectory of your project instead of traversing up the hierarchy to find the file?  Then you can be sure that a relative path such as /resources/B.h would always point to your file even if it moves.